Why the difference in checking for value of pd.DataFrame vs pd.Series if value in index?
I'm working with a pandas DataFrame and I noticed a difference in behavior when using the in operator.
Here’s an example to illustrate this:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [4, 5, 6], 'b': [7, 8, 9]})

print(1 in df)
print(type(df))

print(1 in df["a"])
print(type(df["a"]))

Output:
False
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
True
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

The most straightforward difference is that of course one object is a DataFrame, the other is a Series; nonetheless, I was not really expecting 1 to be found in the Index of the Series and this expression evaluating to True. Especially as it is False for the DataFrame.
Is there an explanation why I should have been expecting this?

In both cases the in operator calls __contains__ to test membership. Both pd.DataFrame and pd.Series are subclasses of NDFrame, which has this method defined as follows:
    def __contains__(self, key) -> bool:
        """True if the key is in the info axis"""
        return key in self._info_axis

So, under the hood the following happens:
print(df._info_axis)
# Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object')

print(df.__contains__(1))
# False

# approx.: 1 in ['a', 'b']

print(df['a']._info_axis)
# RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)

print(df['a'].__contains__(1))
# True

# approx.: 1 in [0, 1, 2]

I.e., the difference lies in the fact that a df uses df.columns as the 'info axis', while a series, such as df['a'], naturally must use series.index.

Iterating over a DataFrame returns its columns.
# list(df)
['a', 'b']

Thus print(1 in df) will check if the DataFrame contains a column named 1, not a value.
When running print(1 in df['a']) it will check if 1 in in the Series index (which is the case since the index is [0, 1, 2]):
If you want to check presence in the index/columns, better be explicit:
1 in df.index      # True
1 in df.columns    # False
1 in df['a'].index # True

If you want to check if the DataFrame/Series contains a specific value (not index/column) use:
1 in df['a'].values # False
4 in df['a'].values # True

1 in df.values      # False
4 in df.values      # True

Or numpy.isin:
np.isin(1, df) # False
np.isin(4, df) # True

np.isin(1, df['a']) # False
np.isin(4, df['a']) # True


Followup question, list(df["a"]) returns the values of the Series, is in using the Series without such a conversion then?

@E.R. what do you mean by "such a conversion"?

@E.R. no, there is no conversion, this calls the __contains__ method (like in normal python)

The 1 in df["a"] is actually checking for the existence of 1 in the indexes, not the values of the "a" column. You can simply check it by dropping the row with index=1 and compare the result:
# Before drop
print(1 in df["a"])
# Afer drop
df = df.drop(index=1)
print(1 in df["a"])

To check the membership among the values of the column "a" I would recommend using something like the to_list() conversion or .values attribute:
print(1 in df["a"].to_list())
print(1 in df["a"].values)

